# Do Whatsapp bots (just like Telegram bots) actually exist and work?

Tags: chat, bots, whatsapp, chatbot

For a while now I have been trying to see if I can get a Whatsapp bot running, in a similar fashion to how Telegram bots work.

I found quite some ambiguous sources or half baked projects that are supposed to be provide Whatsapp bot functionality, but in fact nothing seems to be actually working.

To my knowledge, Whatsapp (unlike Telegram) does not have a public API or openly documented protocol. Does anyone know if it is even possible at all to "automate" communication through Whatsapp, as in send and receive messages, and how? Or would anyone have any good leading points to start developing one myself?

Answer (score 1):

[ https://umstechlabs.com/ai-chatbot/]

The terms WhatsApp Chatbots, WhatsApp Bot, Messenger Bot, and Chatbot have one thing in common — they are all ways to refer to a Bot. Wikipedia provides a great definition for bots: “A Chatterbot, Chatbot, or simply Bot is a text-based dialogue system, which allows you to chat with a technical system.

Bots are everywhere and businesses are changing towards micro apps and cognitive bots for B2B andB2C. There are a few libraries to make your own WhatsApp Bot. A small python framework to create a whatsapp bot, with regex-callback. WhatsApp bot: Send message to a large list of numbers using whatsapp web.

Whatsapp bot without coding. With Xenioo you can create your bot Visually, boost it with AI and Integrations.

Answer (score 0):

try AutoResponder for WA by TK Studio

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforwa&hl=en

it can make conversations using **DialogFlow** which is support **Webhook**, and **Webhook** will send the message to a URL via POST, and from there you can save the message or specific variable to the database and respond it back to **DialogFlow**.

or you just use the AutoResponder for simple conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when it comes to comparing Whatsapp(chat)bots to Telegram bots there is a huge gap of availability, in the terms of that Telegram is open source and there is an endless count of varied bots of choice made by the community, aside from whatsapp bots mainly developed by official or affiliated companies of whatsapp.
So I haven't found anthing yet more useful bot other than different tastes of chatbots, auto replyers and message schedulers.

At the other side, some Telegram bots are capable of sending specific web searches within the chat, news feeds, reminders, games (and not mentioning the useful bots for groups) etc.

I have been doing some research on this topic lately and there actually are ways you can bridge Telegram messages to Whatsapp.

If you might be interested I found 2 ways of doing this (there may be more); bridging by code with Matterbridge or going the easy way with thirs-party API and automation services. Dropped some links below.

shorturl.at/klFR7
shorturl.at/loBEF

Haven't done it myself so not sure if bot functionality may be affected on chat at the other end though.